# Как получить GoogleMap в Fragment?

Tags: java, android

Получаю ошибку

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.eranewgames.twotable.Fragments.Map.onCreateView(Map.java:24)
```

главный активти`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {`

Фрагмент

```
public class Map extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, null);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment= (SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        GoogleMap googleMap=mapFragment.getMap();

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        return view;
    }
}
```

map.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Как бы сказать, весь этот код работал в апи 19. Сейчас же. какая то проблема с ней.

Как быть мне в таком случае?

Мне надо получить GoogleMap...

Comment: Попробуйте скастовать getActivity к AppCompatActivity

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, там смысл в том что в AppCompatActivity нет getSupportFragmentManager. Приходиться использовать Fragment manager. А разве нельзя под ругому...

Comment: Вы что то путаете. Как раз таки в аппКомпат есть саппортМенеджер.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вообщем все решил проблемму, на стеке нашел похожую ссылку там чувак такой же проблемой мучился...всем спс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас импортирован не тот фрагмент.
Вместо `import android.app.Fragment` пропишите `import  android.support.v4.app.Fragment`